# Let's get critical: Dec 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Data Science Stack Exchange](http://datascience.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Hashing Trick - what actually happens](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/1244/hashing-trick-what-actually-happens)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Machine learning - features engineering from date/time data](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/2368/machine-learning-features-engineering-from-date-time-data)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Rough vs Fuzzy vs Granular Computing](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/2349/rough-vs-fuzzy-vs-granular-computing)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Scalable Outlier/Anomaly Detection](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/2293/scalable-outlier-anomaly-detection)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Methods for standardizing / normalizing different rank scales](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/1240/methods-for-standardizing-normalizing-different-rank-scales)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Modelling Unevenly Spaced Time Series](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/2395/modelling-unevenly-spaced-time-series)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [How to calculate classification accuracy with confusion matrix?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/2348/how-to-calculate-classification-accuracy-with-confusion-matrix)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Collaborative Social Network Visualization](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/1241/collaborative-social-network-visualization)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Small project ideas for Machine Learning](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/2343/small-project-ideas-for-machine-learning)

**Net Score: -5** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

- [Neural Networks getting stuck at local optima](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/2362/neural-networks-getting-stuck-at-local-optima)

**Net Score: -5** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 5)

---